# Joomla 3.10 move to new database backend - error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I moved my running Joomla site to a new mariadb database backend (running in a docker conatianer).
After changing the Joomla configuration parameters to access new backend everything seems to be fine.

But then I renamed the old database and I get error:

`Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/html/vco-rn.de/vco/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260 Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session`

Old MariaDB: 10.5
Docker MariaDB: 10.6

Any idea?

renamed database - renamed back so it worked again.

Comment: I don't understand why the old database is still needed even if I changed the settings in Joomla to new server?

Comment: Now I changed the configuration.php again and put in "localhost:3339" as database host. This port does not exist, my database is running on port 3336.
And the Joomla instance is still running???? Is there something cached?